# No internet after reboot without restarting networking service

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I've got a couple of Ubuntu servers (18.04.3). They're connected to the internet and to a private local network. But straight after rebooting a server, they're not connected with the internet. I have to connect to the server via the local network and restart the `networking` service to connect them.

> cat /etc/network/interface:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#internet
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#local network
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

> sudo systemctl status networking.service (after reboot):

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-09-23 12:19:57 UTC; 22min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 829 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 802 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 829 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 23 12:19:52 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Sep 23 12:19:52 ifup[829]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.eth0
Sep 23 12:19:57 ifup[829]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.eth1
Sep 23 12:19:57systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

> sudo systemctl status networking.service (after restarting network service):

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-09-23 12:43:52 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 4151 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4286 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4272 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4286 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4702)
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service
           ├─4355 /sbin/dhclient -1 -4 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth0.leases eth0
           └─4451 /sbin/dhclient -1 -4 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth1.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth1.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth1.leases eth1

Sep 23 12:43:52  ifup[4286]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.3 on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x28c16f37)
Sep 23 12:43:52  ifup[4286]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.2
Sep 23 12:43:52  ifup[4286]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.2
Sep 23 12:43:52  dhclient[4409]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x376fc128)
Sep 23 12:43:52  dhclient[4409]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.3 on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x28c16f37)
Sep 23 12:43:52  dhclient[4409]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.2
Sep 23 12:43:52  dhclient[4409]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.3 from 192.168.0.2
Sep 23 12:43:52  dhclient[4409]: bound to 192.168.0.3 -- renewal in 2147483648 seconds.
Sep 23 12:43:52  ifup[4286]: bound to 192.168.0.3 -- renewal in 2147483648 seconds.
Sep 23 12:43:52  systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how I can fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 and up rely heavily on Netplan for their network configurations, they should NOT be relying on `/etc/network/interfaces` anymore for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You should be using Netplan to config your network interfaces.
Here in this link You can find easy examples
The first one is of an interface with DHCP client.
[netplan.io](https://netplan.io/examples).
You can start by checking the files located here:

> ls /etc/netplan/

Edit the one you find to look like this (indentation is very important):
`network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true`

Then:

> sudo netplan try

This will check if your edit is correct and inform You of any mistakes. Then

> sudo netplan apply